# What standard C functions does libgcc depend on?

Tags: c, kernel, osdev

I have a cross compiler with libgcc compiled for the target platform, but no standard C library is present. What functions does libgcc depend on and where can I find that information?

Answer (score 0):

These are the C functions that libgcc depends on::

1. strlen
2. malloc
3. free
4. memset
5. abort

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Can you cite some source?